# How to prove the cardinality of set of even and odd integers are equal?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

> Let $A$ be the set of all even integers. Let $B$ be the set of all odd integers.
>
> How do we prove that $|A|=|B|$?

I understand that I need to establish a bijection, but how do I go about doing that?

Any advice would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Take the map defined by $f(n)=n+1$ it defines a bijection between the even integers and odd integers.

Answer (score 2):

$$x\in A\leftrightarrow x+1\in B$$
$$\dots$$
$$-4\leftrightarrow-3$$
$$-2\leftrightarrow-1$$
$$0\leftrightarrow1$$
$$2\leftrightarrow3$$
$$4\leftrightarrow5$$
$$\dots$$

Comment: What exactly do you mean by this? Can you add some words to explain this. I am quite lost.

Comment: We associate with any number $x$ in set A (the evens) the number $x+1$ in set $B$ (the odds). End.

Comment: I understand that, but how do I formally explain your original answer? I can't just show a few and write "..." and that be a formal proof. And in order to show bijection (in formally written proofs), I need to show surjection and injection...

Comment: @sgerbhctim There exists an inverse function $x\in\B\leftrightarrow x-1\in\A$, so it is already a bijection.

Answer (score 1):

Connect the nth odd number i.e 2n-1 with the nth even number i.e 2n in your bijection.

Comment: Besides, I think that if two sets are countably infinite, both of them have equal cardinality